# Shortcut to use LINQ

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, linq

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742311.aspx

Based on the link above you have to make a detour before you can use syntax code LINQ for SharePoint.

If you have to do the same approach for SharePoint 2013, do you still have to do these steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are asking if you need to create the LINQ to SharePoint Proxy Code to use LINQ to SharePoint in SharePoint 2013, the answer is yes.